# Zend_Soap_Server Procedure 'sendsth' not present

Tags: zend-framework, wsdl, soaplite

we have a Zend_Soap_Server and a corresponding client, based on the same WSDL and the method "sendsth" is handled correctly if called from the PHP client.

Now I need to call it from perl so I create a client with SOAP::Lite, again using the same WSDL. When I call the method from the client I get an error in the server:

PHP Fatal error:  Procedure 'sendsth' not present in /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Soap/Server.php

Do you have an idea what could be wrong or how to debug that?

Interesting aspect:
even if I wrap the call to $server->handle() in a try/catch block the program crashes exactly there